# Is the time spent flying in a Sailplane concidered a valid flight hour for a LAPL / PPL license?

Tags: flight-training, easa-regulations, glider, sailplane

I live in the Netherlands.

In order to get a Light aircraft pilot licence (LAPL) license 30 flight hours are demanded, A private pilot licence (PPL) requires to have 45 flight hours.

flying in a Sailplane is lower-priced then a motorized airplane in my country.

So I'm wondering if flying in a Sailplane is concidered a valid flight hour for a LAPL / PPL license.

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, under the CAA (and as [a CVn](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/753/a-cvn) mentions, it may vary across EASA land, regardless of SERA), [these are the rules:](https://www.caa.co.uk/General-aviation/Pilot-licences/EASA-requirements/LAPL/LAPL-(A)-requirements/)

> The privileges of your licence will only remain valid if you have
>   completed, in the last 24 months, as pilot of an aeroplane or TMG:
>
> ```
> At least 12 hours flight time as PIC, including 12 take-offs and landings; and
> Refresher training of at least 1 hour of total flight time with an instructor.
> ```

That document also explains that:

> A LAPL for aeroplanes will allow you to act as pilot in command (PIC)
>   on two classes of aircraft: either a single-engine piston aeroplane
>   (land) or touring motor glider (TMG) with a maximum take-off mass of
>   2000 kg or less, carrying a maximum of 3 passengers, with no more than
>   4 persons on board.

So I think that, in the UK, you can't act as PIC on a sailplane and so can't count any hours toward your LAPL

However, TMG flying is very cheap, if you can find one for hire

Comment: I guess you are right, however, I think that flying in a sailplane will improve pilot skills and knowledge about aviation. So it doesn't hurt.

Comment: @Julian you are absolutely right.  All else being equal, a glider pilot transitioning to power almost always makes a better power pilot.